# Blender and pycharm

Tags: python, scripting, external-applications

I'm trying to configure pycharm so it can autocomplete blender python. When searching the web, I only found a solution to autocomplete bge. This was done using preconfigurated files though. Is there a way I can get this to work?

---

Debug error when running refresh_python_api.bat:

```
RNA Warning: Current value "0" matches no enum in 'EnumProperty', 'compute_device_type', 'default'
RNA Warning: Current value "0" matches no enum in 'EnumProperty', 'addon_filter', 'default'
RNA Warning: Current value "0" matches no enum in 'EnumProperty', 'group_select_mode', 'default'
RNA Warning: Current value "0" matches no enum in 'EnumProperty', 'scene', 'default'
RNA Warning: Current value "0" matches no enum in 'EnumProperty', 'modifier', 'default'
RNA Warning: Current value "0" matches no enum in 'EnumProperty', 'property', 'default'
RNA Warning: Current value "1" matches no enum in 'EnumProperty', 'group_select_mode', 'default'
RNA Warning: Current value "0" matches no enum in 'EnumProperty', 'modifier', 'default'
RNA Warning: Current value "0" matches no enum in 'EnumProperty', 'group', 'default'
RNA Warning: Current value "0" matches no enum in 'EnumProperty', 'name', 'default'
RNA Warning: Current value "0" matches no enum in 'EnumProperty', 'modifier', 'default'
RNA Warning: Current value "0" matches no enum in 'EnumProperty', 'action', 'default'
RNA Warning: Current value "0" matches no enum in 'EnumProperty', 'group', 'default'
RNA Warning: Current value "0" matches no enum in 'EnumProperty', 'scene', 'default'
RNA Warning: Current value "1" matches no enum in 'EnumProperty', 'group_select_mode', 'default'
RNA Warning: Current value "0" matches no enum in 'EnumProperty', 'modifier', 'default'
RNA Warning: Current value "0" matches no enum in 'EnumProperty', 'scene', 'default'
RNA Warning: Current value "0" matches no enum in 'EnumProperty', 'type', 'default'
RNA Warning: Current value "0" matches no enum in 'EnumProperty', 'group', 'default'
RNA Warning: Current value "0" matches no enum in 'EnumProperty', 'group_select_mode', 'default'
RNA Warning: Current value "0" matches no enum in 'EnumProperty', 'modifier', 'default'
RNA Warning: Current value "0" matches no enum in 'EnumProperty', 'shape', 'default'
RNA Warning: Current value "0" matches no enum in 'EnumProperty', 'image', 'default'
RNA Warning: Current value "0" matches no enum in 'EnumProperty', 'pose', 'default'
RNA Warning: Current value "1" matches no enum in 'EnumProperty', 'group_select_mode', 'default'
RNA Warning: Current value "0" matches no enum in 'EnumProperty', 'mask', 'default'
RNA Warning: Current value "0" matches no enum in 'EnumProperty', 'group', 'default'
RNA Warning: Current value "0" matches no enum in 'EnumProperty', 'type', 'default'
RNA Warning: Current value "0" matches no enum in 'EnumProperty', 'action', 'default'
RNA Warning: Current value "0" matches no enum in 'EnumProperty', 'type', 'default'
RNA Warning: Current value "0" matches no enum in 'EnumProperty', 'clip', 'default'
RNA Warning: Current value "0" matches no enum in 'EnumProperty', 'group', 'default'
RNA Warning: Current value "1" matches no enum in 'EnumProperty', 'group_select_mode', 'default'
RNA Warning: Current value "0" matches no enum in 'EnumProperty', 'old_id', 'default'
RNA Warning: Current value "0" matches no enum in 'EnumProperty', 'new_id', 'default'
RNA Warning: Current value "0" matches no enum in 'EnumProperty', 'node_item', 'default'
RNA Warning: Current value "1" matches no enum in 'EnumProperty', 'group_select_mode', 'default'
RNA Warning: Current value "0" matches no enum in 'EnumProperty', 'pose', 'default'
RNA Warning: Current value "0" matches no enum in 'EnumProperty', 'group', 'default'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 2, in <module>
  File "C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender\doc\python_api/pypredef_gen.py", line 1177, in <module>
    main() #just run it! Unconditional call makes it easier to debug Blender script in Eclipse,
  File "C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender\doc\python_api/pypredef_gen.py", line 1144, in main
    rna2predef(path_in_tmp)
  File "C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender\doc\python_api/pypredef_gen.py", line 1053, in rna2predef
    bpy2predef(BASEPATH,"Blender API main module")
  File "C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender\doc\python_api/pypredef_gen.py", line 1002, in bpy2predef
    file = open(filepath, "w")
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Program Files\\Blender Foundation\\Blender\\doc\\python_api\\pypredef-tmp\\bpy.py'
Error: Not freed memory blocks: 124, total unfreed memory 0.030273 MB

Blender quit
```

Comment: http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/User:Ideasman42/BlenderAsPyModule

Comment: Is this what I'm looking for?

Comment: Here is a tutorial I used and it worked for me. [How to Set Up PyCharm for Blender](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_albQaDGaHI)

Comment: @BertVdB yes. I have followed the tutorial on Windows with no success though. But then again, it was my first time compiling C code so it might be a beginners mistake.

Answer (score 6):

I found that the script mentioned by neowitch had some shortcomings (the fact that data and context were assigned at the top of bpy.py made pycharm sad), so I made a modified version:

https://github.com/mutantbob/pycharm-blender

Unfortunately, right now it does not offer pre-dumped API stubs.  You'll have to run it either from the command line, or from a text buffer inside blender.  Github isn't really set up to offer pre-built packages (which is essentially what a precomputed set would be).

Also, there are a couple of techniques for getting the generated python into the namespace of your pycharm that I consider better than copying into Python's Lib folder

1. add the python_api/pypredef folder to the Project Structure as another source root.
2. add they python_api/pypredef folder to the interpreter's library set (a little trickier, but makes it work in all pycharm projects)

Comment: I'm sorry, but I do not understand where your script is better than the original... When I run your refresh_python it gives an error...

Comment: It worked on my linux laptop.  If you're using windows run it from a text buffer inside blender, or you can read the shell script to learn the command-line invocation.  If there's some other sort of error, i can not troubleshoot the error without knowing what the error is.

Comment: When I run this script inside blender, blender crashes...

Comment: This is the full error when I run the *.bat script:

Comment: Error: Not freed memory blocks: 124, total unfreed memory 0.030273 MB

Comment: The error is to long to add it in a comment, I will update my post.

Comment: It is strange that it is failing to create the bpy.py file.  Does the directory mentioned in the error message exist?  When I ran it on Linux the directory got created (although i have not yet found the code that did it).

Comment: Yes, I checked. The directory exists!

Comment: I'm having the same problem as @BertVdB. I downloaded the script and invoked Blender 2.78 to run it (on Windows). It works for a few seconds then fails with `Error: Not freed memory blocks: 124, total unfreed memory 0.030273 MB`. The last line it printed before that is `updating: mathutils.py`. The script did generate a bunch of Python files in a `pypredef/` subdirectory but I have no idea if they're complete.

Answer (score 4):

[Answered on blenderartists in Dec 2015](http://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?389012-Best-way-for-developing-under-Blender-with-external-Editor-%28PyCharm%29&p=2987094&viewfull=1#post2987094)

1. Download pydev-blender.zip from http://airplanes3d.net/pydev-000_e.xml

Quoted from ba:

2. unzip into Blender folder(where blender.exe is).
3. go into doc folder and run refresh_python_api.bat.
4. go into doc\python_api\pypredef folder and change all extensions to .py instead of pypredef.
5. cut or copy contents of pypredef folder to you Python's Lib folder.*

Be warned, that zip is from some time between 2011 and 2013. It's all Blender 2.5 and I cannot say if or what changes have been made since then.

*EDIT: After working with pycharm for a while, I strongly recommend Mutant Bob's method of adding the generated python file folder to either the Interpreter or the Project Structure instead of copying them to the Python Lib!

Comment: This doesn't work correctly for me. I configured an interpreter path to look up the pypredef folder, but PyCharm still doesn't know about `bpy.props` for example. I tried adding the single files instead of the folder, but they disappeared after restarting PyCharm. I just have `import bpy` at the top of a python module, then try to use it like `bpy.props.BoolProperty(...)`. Any ideas?

Comment: I had the same problem when I started working with the blender interface and it is still something I haven't found a perfect solution for tbh. Some time ago I found this definition: https://github.com/nazodane/pydev_predef
I'm using both this and the definition above in conjunction. That seems to cover everything.
Download the repository, In PyCharm-installation-folder/bin locate idea.properties, open with nodepad and change idea.max.intellisense.filesize to 999999 (99999 works just fine too)

Then add the predev folder to your project via Project Structure > Add Content Root

Comment: That sounds like a better solution, but it's a shame the defs don't contain `bpy.context` and `bpy.data` =( I wish there would be just autocompletion files shipped with Blender itself...